# Illegal start of expression when printing a line of characters

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I'm trying to create a method that will print a line of *n* characters above and below the actual text. Basically borders for the readable text.

Instead of creating the `String bar = "======================";` I would like the method to simply fill the line with `=` to a specified number of characters.

here's what I have:

```
String title = "Program 1";
String bar = "======================";
String text = "readable text here";

public String printOutput(){

  return (title + '\n' + bar + '\n' + text + '\n' + bar);

}//end printOutput
```

for the return statement I have tried using this but it didn't work:

```
return (title + '\n' + String.fill(58, =) ); // fill a line of length 58 with ='s
```

is something wrong with my syntax? Netbeans complains about an "Illegal start of expression" twice.

Comment: What didn't work? Compiler error? Wrong output? Exception? More info needed.

Comment: netbeans said, before i compiled, "illegal start of expression" twice

Comment: There is no `String.fill` method and even if there were, you would have to quote the `=`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the String.fill call (and couldn't find any documentation on this from the API)

Taking that into account I think the following is along the lines of what you're looking for:

```
char [] output;
output = new char[58];
Arrays.fill(output,'=');
return new String(output);
```

Note that you'll also need to import java.util.Arrays class.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the required format using the following snippet as well:

```
String.format("%58", "=").replace(" ","=");
```

String.fill() is not documented here(http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)